# What is the most efficient way to automate your Instagram?

Tags: selenium, automation, instagram, instagram-api, browser-automation

Over the past few weeks, I've spent some time researching about Instagram automation the goal being to have a program that can like and comment for me. I've come up with the following solutions:

1. Use a ***browser automation library*** like **selenium** to navigate through Instagram's website.
   Cons: really botchy code that becomes useless as soon as Instagram renames their css classes which they do from time to time
2. Have a ***Android emulator*** running and automate that. 
   Cons: every instance of that emulator would require like 2 gigs of storage and would be really inefficient.

So how do for example apps on the play-/app store do it? They only have the small processing power of the phone available and still run effortless in the background.

Is there another solution that I'm missing?

Comment: A combination of 1+2 is using _visual_ automation with [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or (in the browser) with [SeeShell](https://a9t9.com/seeshell/web-automation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it at the end was that I used the Instagram Private API for Instagram on GitHub:
https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api

That way I didn't have to emulate an entire device actually browsing through Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to automate Instagram is to use the [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api). Using that API you can publish photos with users, tags and locations [1]. I don't find any immediate mention of Stories etc., but most likely if you work more with the API you find where/how to do that.

The also linked [Instagram Platform API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) seems to be in a state of discontinuation.

As you tagged your question "Selenium", no, Selenium does not provide a reasonable approach for interfacing with Instagram as Selenium provides no way to make POST requests. You could try to automate the website through Selenium, but using the API is far more straightforward, less prone to layout changes and the officially sanctioned way.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing